# coffee -> javascript -> typescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typescript

I'm converting coffeescripts to typescript and have trouble with one simple delay type function.

The coffeescript:

```
ise.utils.delay = (->
  timer = 0
  (callback, ms) ->
    clearTimeout timer
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms)
)()
```

The produced javascript:

```
  ise.utils.delay = (function() {
    var timer;
    timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      return timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
```

When I enter the produced js into a typescript file I get a compile error.

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: But you *can* tell us what error is, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above code is all the code you have, then you are missing `var ise = { utils: { delay: {}}}`

I think what you are actually looking for is modules in TypeScript like below

```
module ise.utils {
    var timer = 0;
    export function delay(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        return timer = setTimeout(callback, ms)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```js
module ise {
  export module utils {
    var timer = 0;
    export
    function delay(callback, ms) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      return timer = setTimeout(callback, ms)
    };
```

...
Thanks...